# RPC style request with MQTT

Tags: request, response, rpc, synchronous, mqtt

what is the best way to implement RPC style communication (synchronous request/response) with MQTT? Or would it even make sense to put another interface (e.g. REST api) into use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

What I've done in my applications is include a response topic in my messages. The sender would generate a topic using a uuid then subscribe to that topic. Then would send a message containing the response topic, the receiver(s) would send a reply to this topic. Once the send receives the reply it would unsubscribe to the topic. Both sender and receiver are asynchronous and yet can perform a transaction.

Pseudo code:

```
sender
   generate uuid
   subscribe( topic=uuid )
   msg = {
      ... 
      resp_topic: uuid
   } 
   publish( topic, msg )

receiver
   on_message 
      topic is from sender
         do some work
         publish( sender_data['resp_topic'], result )

sender
   on_message
      topic is resp_topic
          get result
          unsubscribe( resp_topic )
```

Comment: Does your solution also works if you have a horizontal scaling of your server implementation?

Answer (score 1):

MQTT is a PUB/SUB system and doesn't lend itself well to RPC. While you could possibly shoehorn something on top of MQTT to simulate the synchronicity required, you are probably better off looking for a system which provides real RPC semantics.

That said, depending on your application, you can subscribe to multiple MQTT topics and simulate round-trip communication by PUBlishing on one topic and listening for a response on a second topic. Note though, that this is by nature not synchronous.

For example, you could PUBlish a "question" to `topic/query` and expect a response on `topic/response`.

Comment: OK, thx. Is there something I should pay attention to? Concerning topic structure, request id or synchronization?

Comment: I've added a small example, but as I said earlier, it seems to me that MQTT is maybe not ideally suited to your use-case. :)

Comment: It is for a mobile multiplayer game. I've chosen MQTT because of little overhead and low strain on cpu and battery. I am a beginner at distributed computing, so it might be not the best choice...

Comment: @Gargamel The best way to think of MQTT is as a network level IPC for your applications that need a last will messaging, QoS for message queues, and/or one to many messages.

While RPC calls are the other way around being many to one messaging and should be handled over a json based RESTful API.

Distributed computing is more about Boinc/OpenMPI/Beowulf/Hadoop clustering systems. Namely large data crunching.

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages built on top of mqtt that may do what you want. One such example for node.js is [mqtt-json-rpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-json-rpc), which mimics RPC over some other WAMP-style stacks like Crossbar.io.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for some standard answers for json-rpc over mqtt and how to handle topics.  People tend to reference [mqtt-json-rpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-json-rpc), which says this:

> Internally, remote methods are assigned to MQTT topics.

but if that's the way you do it - one topic per method - then that would be a concurrency problem unless you took two extra precautions: first, the id would have to be guaranteed to be some kind of per-request GUID, and second, the client would have to compare that GUID against its own and discard responses to any requests made by another client.  These things are probably a good idea anyway but the jsonrpc 2.0 spec doesn't speak to this and, in fact, use of the transaction ID is encouraged by optional.

I'm thinking that this is the wrong approach and that I should use a per-client topic. The way this would work is using patterns:

```
topic:  /rpc/${clientID}/request
response: /rpc/${clientID}/response
```

or
topic:  /rpc/${clientID}/methodname/request
response:  /rpc/${clientID}/methodname/response

The RPC server would listen with a wildcard, match that client id, and send the response down the correct pipe.  I'm not sure this is a great idea, either, though.  My main concern here is that I'm not convinced MQTT brokers are really intended to have such ephemeral topics.  Mosquitto for instance lets you turn persistence on globally, but I'm not sure if you send QoS=0 does that bypass persistence, and I'm even less certain how consistent any behavior around this would be across the many different brokers out there.

Comment: Please don't start topics with a leading `/` while technically in spec it is a really bad habit, it adds an extra `null` to the start of the topic tree and breaks things like Shared Subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks, @hardillb - I didn't realize that